# Prove the following inequality $|a^xqb^{1-x}-a^{1-x}qb^x|\leq |2x-1||aq-qb|$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove the following inequality $|a^xqb^{1-x}-a^{1-x}qb^x|\leq |2x-1||aq-qb|$ for $0<x<1$ and $a,b>0$

I tried to deform the problem and solve it using derivatives as follows:

$|a^xqb^{1-x}-a^{1-x}qb^x|\leq |2x-1||aq-qb|$,  $a,b>0$, $x\in (0,1)$

$\Rightarrow |a^xb^{1-x}-a^{1-x}b^x|\leq |2x-1||a-b|$, $a,b>0$, $x\in (0,1)$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{a}{b})^x-(\frac{a}{b})^{1-x}\leq (2x-1)(\frac{a}{b}-1)$, $a\geq b>0,x\in [\frac{1}{2},1)$

$\Rightarrow \frac{f(t)-f(1)}{t-1}\leq 2x-1, t\geq 1$ where $f(t)=t^x-t^{1-x}, x\in [\frac{1}{2},1)$.

I realized that the left hand side is $f'(s),s\in [1,t]$, but I am stuck here and don't know what to do next. I hope to receive some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't obtain the exact inequality mentioned in your post but hopefully the following helps. The inequality is trivial if $x = 1/2$ or $a = b$ so assume without loss of generality that $x\neq 1/2$ and $a > b$. Then we have $$\left|\left(
\frac{a}{b}\right)^{x}bq-\left(
\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1-x}bq\right| = |bq|\cdot|2x-1|\cdot\left|
\frac{a}{b}\right|^{\xi}\cdot|\log(a)-\log(b)|$$
for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $1-x$ using the mean value theorem. Again use the mean value theorem to obtain $$\left|\left(
\frac{a}{b}\right)^{x}bq-\left(
\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1-x}bq\right| = |bq|\cdot|2x-1|\cdot\left|
\frac{a}{b}\right|^{\xi}\cdot|a-b|\cdot\left|\frac{1}{\eta}\right|$$ for some $\eta\in (b, a)$. Now use the fact that $(a/b)^{\xi} < a/b$ and $1/\eta < 1/b$ to obtain $$\left|\left(
\frac{a}{b}\right)^{x}bq-\left(
\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1-x}bq\right| = |2x-1|\cdot|aq-qb|\cdot \left|\frac{a}{b}\right|.$$